# Chainlink vs Oraclize

Tags: oracles, chainlink

I am trying to choose between Chainlink vs Oraclize. Can anyone advise the difference between both solution?

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 2):

Oraclize is live now, if you absolutely MUST have an oracle solution.  Long-term, being decentralized makes Chainlink a more reliable, robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Oraclize is a more centralized solution where as Chainlink offers a 'slider' for decentralization. You can choose how many nodes you want to serve your smart contract and you can choose how much of reputation, how much collateral the nodes serving you need to have and from how many different sources there should be data gathered that get's aggregated in the Chainlink network itself before injecting into the smart contract. Oraclize is the goto solution if you need an oracle service right now. If you wan't to build for the future, Chainlink is your thing. Contact the team at support@chain.link, they are very friendly and helpful with your questions